# Creating a new dictionary that contains the number of elements for each key

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary that looks like this, and I want to create a different dictionary that has the same keys but the values are the amount of elements associated with each key.
(e.g. 29:['5'], 30:['6'], 31:['1'])

```
 29: ['15', '26', '16', '24', '4'],
 30: ['25', '16', '18', '21', '19', '4'],
 31: ['2'],
 32: ['17', '20', '4'],
 33: ['28', '20', '22', '4'],
 34: ['24', '30', '9', '4', '36'],
 35: ['33', '27', '22', '23', '32', '40', '17', '10', '20', '27', '28', '5'],
 36: ['34', '5', '39'],
 37: ['30', '28', '25', '29', '24', '21', '5'],
 38: ['29', '27', '33', '35', '22', '26', '4'],
 39: ['2'],
 40: ['4', '41'],
 41: ['40', '23', '20', '3'],
 42: ['36', '21', '31', '2'],
 43: ['35', '28', '37', '5'],
 44: ['38', '20', '33', '28', '4', '48', '45'],
 45: ['38', '43', '29', '30', '4'],
 46: ['39', '34', '42', '31', '36', '2'],
 47: ['41', '32', '20', '32', '40', '2'],
 48: ['45', '44', '38', '37', '49', '37', '43', '4'],
 49: ['48', '35', '43', '44', '43', '45', '3']}
```

Comment: Why do you want `['5']` -- a list containing a string -- instead of `5`, an int, as the value?  That doesn't seem to have many uses.

Comment: @DSM is right, so in my answer I just return the length, in case you want ['3'] you have to replace `k:len(v)` by `k:[str(len(v))]`, but it seems to have no much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension for iterate over the old dictionary and create the new dictionary with the following code:

```
>>> old_dict = {29: ['15', '26', '16', '24', '4'], 30: ['25', '16', '18', '21', '19', '4'], 31: ['2'], 32: ['17', '20', '4'], 33: ['28', '20', '22', '4'], 34: ['24', '30', '9', '4', '36'], 35: ['33', '27', '22', '23', '32', '40', '17', '10', '20', '27', '28', '5'], 36: ['34', '5', '39'], 37: ['30', '28', '25', '29', '24', '21', '5'], 38: ['29', '27', '33', '35', '22', '26', '4'], 39: ['2'], 40: ['4', '41'], 41: ['40', '23', '20', '3'], 42: ['36', '21', '31', '2'], 43: ['35', '28', '37', '5'], 44: ['38', '20', '33', '28', '4', '48', '45'], 45: ['38', '43', '29', '30', '4'], 46: ['39', '34', '42', '31', '36', '2'], 47: ['41', '32', '20', '32', '40', '2'], 48: ['45', '44', '38', '37', '49', '37', '43', '4'], 49: ['48', '35', '43', '44', '43', '45', '3']}
>>> new_dict = {k:len(v) for k,v in old_dict.iteritems()}
>>> print new_dict
 {32: 3, 33: 4, 34: 5, 35: 12, 36: 3, 37: 7, 38: 7, 39: 1, 40: 2, 41: 4, 42: 4, 43: 4, 44: 7, 45: 5, 46: 6, 47: 6, 48: 8, 49: 7, 29: 5, 30: 6, 31: 1}
```